Did I understand well the meaning of past perfect

I saw him again last year, and I had thought he was tall. But when I saw him last week, I noticed that he was not that tall. I suppose I had stars in my eyes.

This means that she changed her mind as soon as she saw him last week. Is this correct?

I saw him again last year, and I thought he was tall. But when I saw him last week, I noticed that he was not that tall. I suppose I had stars in my eyes.

This means she changed her mind after seeing him again last week surely at the end of the meeting .Is this correct ?
And why it is not "I'd had stars in my eyes" because it happened the first time she saw him.
I think that suppose is present so there is no need of past perfect

I think your Past Perfect and I had thought he was tall is at best misleading. It gives the impression you [had] thought he was tall before you saw him last year, but your next sentence goes against that interpretation. I'd suggest I saw him again last year, and at that time I thought he was tall, or more naturally, When I saw him again last year I thought he was tall. You definitely don't want any Past Perfect verb forms there. Also, it would be far more natural to say ...I realized that he was not that tall - "noticed" is a bit odd for a change of opinion.

...as ever, if you don't know for sure that you need Past Perfect, you probably shouldn't use it. Far too many learners overuse Perfect verb forms.

That is what I thought but was not sure as I found this example as an answer to a question

And thé last sentence ?

You could use the Past Perfect there (I suppose I had had stars in my eyes), but imho that's really klunky. It's slightly better contracted to I suppose I'd had stars in my eyes - but honestly, I think you're better off sticking to Simple Past. I have to say that again in your first sentence is really off-putting, though. Why didn't you think he was tall the first time you saw him? Before seeing him again last year? It makes me think you're just playing with words, not imagining and describing real / plausible scenarios.

An easy rule to follow is to use past perfect only when you must order things that are not already clear. Otherwise, we can figure it out: "When I drank three tequilas, I forgot that I had downed three cabernets. That explains the traffic stop, the police concluded."

@YosefBaskin, I'm impressed that with all those drinks you can still get your tenses in the right order!

@YvesLefol, what do you mean by surely at the end of the meeting? If you mean "it was only at the end of my time seeing him that I noticed...", then no. The tenses are not that precise. When is the key word, and it implies two actions that are simultaneous.

Why would be I'd had stars in my eyes klunky. By the way it is not my sentence but example given as an answer to a question

We don't need to get fancy with "I'd had stars in my eyes" when "l had stars in my eyes" says it all. That's why.

No explanation why I had stars in my eyes says it all

It's obvious from the context that the speaker means "I had stars in my eyes when I saw him last year". As others have said, it's clunky to use a perfect tense when the meaning is clear without it.

That is also what I thought but need confirmation
